# Create a LAN Access Point on Android device (no Internet needed)

Tags: android, wifi, lan

I need to implement the following functionality:

- The application should programmatically make the Android device a LAN server (i.e. other devices should be able to connect to the network created by the application wirelessly, like connection to the wifi spot, but not to the Internet)
- The application should be able to register the devices connected to the application's network
- The application's network should be protected by a password

---

Is it possible to implement such a functionality? Currently, I've only managed to set up a web server on the device using [nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd), but it doesn't seem to be the correct path for doing what I need. I've read some similar questions on SO but either didn't understand the concepts or just couldn't find the appropriate answer.

If it is possible, how should I implement it? Is there anything that I could read about solving a similar problem? Or, maybe, someone has already faced something like that and has some experience with dealing with such a task?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Your requirements aren't quite clear.  Do you want a HTTP server that onoy accepts local wireless connections?  Are you wanting to set up a wi-fi direct type solution? Something else?

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry about ambiguity in the question. I need one device to be able to receive small pieces of data (~5-10kb) from other multiple devices without the Internet connection. Also, I need that device to be able to broadcast the data to all its connected devices. I hope it clarifies my requirements at least a little. I'm also not sure about the choice of technology and was hoping to get some advice on that too (i.e. wifi-direct, tcp or something else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like wifi direct is what you're looking for. Using [WifiP2PManager.createGroup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#createGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)) will allow a device to act as a wireless router if you will, allowing other devices to connect to it as if they were connecting to wifi.

Be warned you will not be able to connect to the device's wifi signal without the random passphrase generated by the device. You can find the passphrase by calling [WifiP2PManager.requestGroupInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#requestGroupInfo(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener)) and passing a [GroupInfoListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener.html). Calling [getPassphrase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html#getPassphrase()) on the [WifiP2PGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html).